# Base64_encode in URL

Tags: php

I am trying to encrypt GET parametar in URL.

```
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
 $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
 $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
 $output = openssl_encrypt($adresa, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
 $xy = base64_encode($output);
 $encoded_uniqid_file = rtrim($xy , '=');

 $click = 'OtvoriProzor("'.$file_path.'&pk='.$sesija->pk.'&adresa='.$encoded_uniqid_file.
 '&IDIstorijaElement='.$element->GetId().'", "Prevod", 700, 500);';
```

then i am getting this url

```
$adresa = str_repeat('=', strlen($adresa) % 4);
if(base64_decode($adresa, true))
{
      $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
      $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
      $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
      $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
      $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

      $adresa = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($adresa), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);           
}
```

My biggest trouble is base64_encode in URL parametars. Will some characters interrupt my script like + = 
I tried to remove this characters, but later in my code need check

```
if(base64_decode($adresa, true))
```

will this evaluate as false if i remove charachters like +,= before this check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64 is not url save. also don't remove the `=` sign.

Use this:

`urlencode($xy)`

instead of

`rtrim($xy , '=');`

You probably need to encode the pk to:

`'&pk='.urlencode($sesija->pk).'&adresa='`

Comment: but i need check if(base64_decode($adresa, true)) i think its impossible to get check with urlencode

Comment: You only need to send the parameter encoded, the $_GET parameter will be decoded automatically

Comment: is taht true Bart this is solution